# What does "go over Wednesday" mean?

Tags: meaning

It's from the 20th episode of the 3rd season of *The Office*. Here's the context:

Creed: When I **went over Wednesday**, for the spot-check, I got a call from Debbie Brown, saying she has an emergency dentist appointment.
Dwight: Emergency dentist appointment.
Creed: Now I’m told she told her manager she had the flu. I’m a trusting guy, but uh, I just wish Debbie Brown had been there. We would have caught this.

Comment: I think it means "when I went over on Wednesday". It is spoken English, small words sometimes get omitted.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I had a different idea, of "go over" meaning "review" but I think you're interpretation is correct.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thanks, I wrote a comment to your answer but did not press "Add" quickly enough. I agreed with your response for the normal usage of those words but I thought this case was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it means "when I went over on Wednesday" or "when I visited [some place] on Wednesday". It is spoken English, small words sometimes get omitted.

A "spot-check" normally means visiting some place to do a quick inspection. This supports the idea that "on" was omitted from the opening phrase.

Comment: If this is the American version of the television programme then I think the omission of _on_ may be dialectal.